# TikZ: How to draw a pattern at the border of a tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I want to draw the shapes of airspaces according to the german VFR map style and I have problems with the restricted areas, ED-R44 in this picture:
[image: Legend of German ICAO Map]
<sub>(source: [flightplanner.de](https://www.flightplanner.de/legenden/ICAOD.png))</sub>

I already found out how to do the airspace A and B,C,D but the fill mechanism doesn't transpose to the hatch pattern I am looking for:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzstyle{EDR}=[draw=red,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red}}]
\tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[EDR] (1,0) -- (4.5,1.5) -- (4,4) -- (1,3.5) -- (2.5,2) -- cycle;

\node at (6,2) {$\rightarrow$};

\draw[EDR] (8,0) rectangle (12,4);
\draw[fill=white,draw=none] (8.5,0.5) rectangle (11.5,3.5);

\draw[D] (13,0) rectangle (17,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: CUrrent state of work as in the MWE]
The problem is, that the white fill doesn't work for arbitraray polygons, but I am unable to think of a way for preaction, postaction or decoration, to make it work.

Comment: please, extend your code snippet to complete small document `beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. this is needed for test your code (it is not fun to write from scratch what you already done. help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry @Zarko, I am using TikZEdit, hence the old code was my complete example. I now expanded it to a complete document which should compile. And please don't get me wrong, I don't want to replicate the whole legend, it is only about the restricted areas with the hatch pattern.

Comment: reproducing complete shoved image is to broad for asking, so in such case your question be closed :-). from the very beginning, I understood that you are only interested in the part, that you interested only for part produced by your mwe. there is not clear, what you like to obtain? the most left image with patterns only band at shape border?

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to make clear, because the image might be confusing without the text above. And exactly, I need to have the hatch pattern only at the border, like in the two rectangles (one with the red hatch, one with the blue solid), but without the trick of drawing white over the hatch, like in the MWE. Basically the result in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282012/change-angle-of-decoration-or-pattern-along-a-path-independently but I have to do it on arbitrary polygons, so I cannot manually define the fill area.

Comment: I am really curious about what your project was. An ICAO500-like map done in tikz? Do you have some website/image, what the overall outcome was?

Comment: @n4pK, I needed it to draw figures for my PhD which needed a simplified ICAO map look. Can you send me a personal message or similar? I try to add a graphic here if I find some time.

Comment: @TobiBS where can I send you a message? Seems like StackExchange [does not have this feature by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537)...

Comment: Mmh, it seems I am also not able to provide the images here in a comment and I don‘t want to put them into the question. Can you maybe leave a hint how to contact you on your profile page, as suggested in the question you are referring, then I can e.g. send you an e-mail?

Comment: @n4pK, if you are still interested, please send me a means of communication or a hint, how I can find you.

Comment: @n4pK, are you still interested in the application?

Comment: @n4pK Send me an e-mail with your e-mail address to stackexchange@tempr.email and I will contact you. Please post another comment here, when you did so.

Comment: @n4pK I received it and replied through my private e-mail, let's continue there. I will delete all comments related to our conversation here in a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER BASED ON YOUR OWN ANSWER**: This avoids the white filling. **UPDATE**: One single style does the job. (I also did the blue contour.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}

\newcounter{tmp}

%\tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]
%<- note that tikzstyle is deprecated

\tikzset{D/.style={
preaction={draw=blue,line width=1pt},
preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
decorate,
},
postaction={
insert path={%
\pgfextra{%
\pgfinterruptpath
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
\path[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
\mySecondList \myList 
;
\end{scope}
\endpgfinterruptpath}
}},
}}



\tikzset{EDR/.style={
preaction={draw=red,line width=1pt},
preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
decorate,
},
postaction={
insert path={%
\pgfextra{%
\pgfinterruptpath
\path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
\mySecondList \myList 
;
\endpgfinterruptpath}
}},
}}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
    next state=draw,
    width=0pt,
    persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{}\xdef\mySecondList{}}
    \pgfextra{\setcounter{tmp}{0}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
        -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
      -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
      {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \stepcounter{tmp}
    \pgfcoordinate{muemmel\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
      {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    \pgfcoordinate{feep\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}      
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList (muemmel\thetmp) -- }%
        \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList (feep\thetmp) -- }}
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
      \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList cycle}}
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{\pgfextra{%\typeout{\myList,\mySecondList}
  }}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
    decorate}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) -- ({sqrt(8)},4) node[midway,sloped,above]{That's just a test!};

\path[EDR]
(1,0) -- (4.5,1.5) -- (4,4) -- (1,3.5) -- (3.5,2) -- cycle;

\path[D] (7,0) -- (9.5,2.5) -- (11,4) -- (9,3.5) -- (8,2) -- cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:  Some very similar question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192824/121799). Using the code written there allowed me to write a command `\DrawBorder`, which I believe does what you want. Note, however, that the present version works for polygons only. (**EDIT**: Added the BCD style, cleaned up the code and added explanations.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations,calc}
%
\def\contourwidth{12pt} 
% Notice that this width enters at two places
% first it defines the widths of the nodes created by \tikzsegment
% but it also defines the overshoot, required when an angle is larger than 
% 180 degrees
\newcommand{\tikzsegment}[3][]{ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192824/121799
\path let
      \p1=($#3-#2$),
      \n1={veclen(\p1)+1.75*\contourwidth}
 in #2 -- #3 
 node[minimum width=\n1, 
         inner sep=0pt, 
         pos=0.5,sloped,rectangle,
         fill=white]{} 
    node[minimum width=\n1, 
         inner sep=0pt, 
         pos=0.5,sloped,rectangle,
         #1] 
     (line){};
}
\newcommand{\DrawBorderA}[2][]{
\begin{scope}
\foreach \point [count=\n] in {#2} {
\ifnum\n=1
\xdef\ClipList{\point --}
\else
\xdef\ClipList{\ClipList \point --}
\fi
\node (prev) at \point {};
}
\xdef\ClipList{\ClipList cycle;}%\typeout{\ClipList}
\clip \ClipList
\foreach \point in {#2} {
\node (new) at \point {};%\typeout{\point}
\tikzsegment[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,
               minimum height={2*\contourwidth}]
              {(prev.center)}{(new.center)}    
\node (prev) at \point {};            
}
\draw[red,line width=2pt] \ClipList                    
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\DrawBorderBCD}[2][]{
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
\foreach \point [count=\n] in {#2} {
\ifnum\n=1
\xdef\ClipList{\point --}
\else
\xdef\ClipList{\ClipList \point --}
\fi
\node (prev) at \point {};
}
\xdef\ClipList{\ClipList cycle;}%\typeout{\ClipList}
\clip \ClipList
\foreach \point in {#2} {
\node (new) at \point {};%\typeout{\point}
\tikzsegment[fill=blue,
               minimum height={2*\contourwidth}]
              {(prev.center)}{(new.center)}
\node (prev) at \point {};            
}             
\end{scope}
\draw[blue,opacity=1,line width=1pt] \ClipList            
s}

% \tikzstyle{EDR}=[draw=red,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red}}]
% \tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\DrawBorderA{(1,0),(4.5,1.5),(4,4),(1,3.5),(2.5,2)}

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\DrawBorderBCD{(1,0),(4.5,1.5),(4,4),(1,3.5),(2.6,2)}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**DISCLAIMER**: It does not yet work with arbitrarily crazy angles (much larger than 270 degrees). Dealing with those will either require brute force, i.e. some fair amount of work, or some clever idea. I plan to revisit this task once I know that this is the way to go.

Comment: In general the results looks like my expectation, but this solution creates problems in my actual file, which is scaled and hence creates nasty effects on some edges.

Comment: That is a nice solution, but shouldn't it be possible to avoid to have the path twice? I know one could save it or one could again build a macro around it, but I think we are very close to a solution which can be completely embedded in a style.

Comment: @TobiBS I am working on that, my attempts use `append after command` and `insert path`. As you probably know, Ti*k*Z can be tricky ... ;-)

Comment: Regarding your comment about tikzstyle: Is it really deprecated now, I was still under the impression of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Comment: Sounds good and I know that TikZ is tricky, but that is the challenge, right?

Comment: @TobiBS Frankly, I don't know if it is really deprecated, but what I do know is that whenever I use it I get angry comments. ;-) And yes, it is a nice challenge....

Comment: good to know, I will avoid it when answering questions of others.

Comment: @TobiBS One more thing: your white filled triangle inside is rather harmless if you draw it on the background layer. The reason why I did not go this way is (a) the challenge and (b) that if you need to put other stuff on backgrounds, it will be slightly  more complicated because you'll need to deal with all the layers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74349/discussion-between-tobibs-and-marmot).

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466028/121799) is a version that does not use `\pgfextra`.

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution for my problem which is based on [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102975/draw-additional-parallel-paths-in-tikz/103088) and furthermore [Polygon drawn with an offset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133655/polygon-drawn-with-an-offset/133670#133670)

```
\tikzstyle{EDR}=[draw=red,line width=1pt,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,postaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt}, fill=white, decorate}]

\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
    next state=draw,
    width=0pt,
    persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
        -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
      -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
      {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
    decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[EDR] (1,0) -- (4.5,1.5) -- (4,4) -- (1,3.5) -- (2.5,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: Is anybody able to propose a good way to create the white area via clipping, instead of my poor mans filling? It works in my current project, but might create issues for others.

Comment: I have added a slightly modified version of your code to my answer which avoids the fill.

Comment: Is it possible to use this pattern also with a not closed path? When I remove the `cycle` I get the error: `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.`.