# TikZ: How to draw a pattern at the border of a not closed tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pattern

"Based on the solution provided at [TikZ: How to draw a pattern at the border of a tikz path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419533/tikz-how-to-draw-a-pattern-at-the-border-of-a-tikz-path/) I was able to do all the graphics in my thesis, except for one shape. As you can see in the graphic" ( ;-) [Filling rule and for pattern at border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466024/filling-rule-and-for-pattern-at-border))

[image]

I would like to draw an open pat, where the beginning and end are not connected, as shown in case c) just that I want to decorate it with a pattern, as can be seen in case a) and b).
Currently I try to help my self by hiding a part of the path with a white rectangle.
The problem is that I can only apply the pattern to closed paths. As soon as I remove the `cycle` at the end of a path that has the style `EDR` or `EDO` I get the error: `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.`

How can I decorate an open path with a pattern? As shown in this figure (modified with inkscape.)

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}

% BEGIN from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820
\newcounter{tmp}

%\tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]
%<- note that tikzstyle is deprecated

\tikzset{D/.style={
    preaction={draw=blue,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
            \path[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
            \mySecondList \myList 
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}



\tikzset{EDR/.style={
    preaction={draw=red,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
  next state=draw,
  width=0pt,
  persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{}\xdef\mySecondList{}}
    \pgfextra{\setcounter{tmp}{0}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
      -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
    -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
    {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \stepcounter{tmp}
    \pgfcoordinate{muemmel\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    \pgfcoordinate{feep\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}      
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList (muemmel\thetmp) -- }%
    \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList (feep\thetmp) -- }}
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
      \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList cycle}}
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{\pgfextra{%\typeout{\myList,\mySecondList}
  }}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
decorate}}
% END from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820

\tikzset{EDO/.style={
    preaction={draw=orange,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node at (-.5,0) {a)};
  \path [EDO] (2.875,0) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75) -- cycle;
  \path [EDR] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0) -- cycle ;
  \fill [white] (.21,.3) rectangle (2.655,-.3);

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
  \node at (-.5,0) {b)};
    \path [EDO] (2.875,0) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75) -- cycle;
    \path [EDR] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0) -- cycle ;
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
    \node at (-.5,0) {c)};
    \path [draw, orange, line width=1pt] (2.875,0) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75);
    \path [draw, red, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a generalization of your code that does that. It distinguishes between closed and non-closed paths.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}

% BEGIN from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820
\newcounter{tmp}
\newif\ifpathisclosed

%\tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]
%<- note that tikzstyle is deprecated

\tikzset{D/.style={
    preaction={draw=blue,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
            \path[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
            \mySecondList \myList 
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}



\tikzset{EDR/.style={
    preaction={draw=red,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
  next state=draw,
  width=0pt,
  persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    %\xdef\myList{}\xdef\mySecondList{}%
    \setcounter{tmp}{0}%
    \global\pathisclosedfalse%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
      -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
    -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
    {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \stepcounter{tmp}%
    \pgfcoordinate{muemmel\number\value{tmp}}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \pgfcoordinate{feep\number\value{tmp}}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}%      
    \ifnum\value{tmp}=1\relax%
     \pgfcoordinate{muemmel0}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
     \pgfcoordinate{feep0}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%      
     \xdef\myList{(muemmel\number\value{tmp})}%
     \xdef\mySecondList{(feep\number\value{tmp})}%
    \else
     \xdef\myList{\myList -- (muemmel\number\value{tmp})}%
     \xdef\mySecondList{(feep\number\value{tmp}) -- \mySecondList}%
    \fi 
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
      \global\pathisclosedtrue%
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{%\typeout{\myList,\mySecondList}%
    \ifpathisclosed%
      \xdef\myList{\myList -- cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList -- cycle}%
      %\typeout{closed \mySecondList \myList }
    \else
      %\typeout{\number\value{tmp}}%
      \xdef\myList{(muemmel0) -- \myList -- cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList -- (feep0) --}%
      %\typeout{not closed \mySecondList \myList }%   
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
decorate}}
% END from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820

\tikzset{EDO/.style={
    preaction={draw=orange,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \path [EDO] (2.875,3) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75) -- cycle;
  \path [EDR] (0,3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0) -- cycle ;
  \fill [white] (.21,3.3) rectangle (2.655,2.7);

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \path [EDO] (2.875,3) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75) -- cycle;
    \path [EDR] (0,3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0) -- cycle ;
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
    \path [EDO,draw, orange, line width=1pt] (2.875,3) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75);
    \path [EDR,draw, red, line width=1pt] (0,3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
    \path [EDO,draw, orange, line width=1pt] (2.875,3) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75);
    \path [EDR,draw, red, line width=1pt,shorten >=6pt] (0,3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) 
    -- ++(-3.125cm-6pt,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Counting from the top, the third (or next-to-last) path is what you get by default. This is because the path does not know that the other path is what it is. To generate your desired output, one has to use `shorten`, see the fourth (or last) picture.

This is a more streamlined version thereof.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations}

% BEGIN from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820


\tikzset{D/.style={
    preaction={draw=blue,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
            \path[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
            \mySecondList \myList 
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}



\tikzset{EDR/.style={
    preaction={draw=red,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifdeco@path@is@closed
\newcounter{deco@count}

\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
  next state=draw,
  width=0pt,
  persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    %\xdef\myList{}\xdef\mySecondList{}%
    \setcounter{deco@count}{0}%
    \global\deco@path@is@closedfalse%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
      -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
    -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
    {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \stepcounter{deco@count}%
    \pgfcoordinate{muemmel\number\value{deco@count}}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \pgfcoordinate{feep\number\value{deco@count}}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}%      
    \ifnum\value{deco@count}=1\relax%
     \pgfcoordinate{muemmel0}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
     \pgfcoordinate{feep0}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%      
     \xdef\myList{(muemmel\number\value{deco@count})}%
     \xdef\mySecondList{(feep\number\value{deco@count})}%
    \else
     \xdef\myList{\myList -- (muemmel\number\value{deco@count})}%
     \xdef\mySecondList{(feep\number\value{deco@count}) -- \mySecondList}%
    \fi 
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
      \global\deco@path@is@closedtrue%
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{%\typeout{\myList,\mySecondList}%
    \ifdeco@path@is@closed%
      \xdef\myList{\myList -- cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList -- cycle}%
      %\typeout{closed \mySecondList \myList }
    \else
      %\typeout{\number\value{deco@count}}%
      \xdef\myList{(muemmel0) -- \myList -- cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList -- (feep0) --}%
      %\typeout{not closed \mySecondList \myList }%   
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
decorate}}
% END from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820

\tikzset{EDO/.style={
    preaction={draw=orange,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \path [EDO,draw, orange, line width=1pt] (2.875,3) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75);
    \path [EDR,draw, red, line width=1pt,shorten >=6pt-\pgflinewidth/2] (0,3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) 
    -- ++(-3.125cm-6pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I cleaned up a bit. However, there is one thing that I did not do: stop using `\pgfextra` for paths. This is something that is to be avoided. In this very case it does seem OK. One could also write a cleaner version, but this would require you to add an extra command for the pattern. Please let me know if you want this to be spelled out.

Comment: Note that this code does not overpaint anything, and cleaned up the original code quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is the remove the `draw` part from the decoration, then draw the lines after the decoration are made, as your third example.

I modified your MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}

% BEGIN from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820
\newcounter{tmp}

%\tikzstyle{D}=[draw=blue,line width=1pt,preaction={clip, postaction={draw=blue,opacity=0.5,line width=12pt}}]
%<- note that tikzstyle is deprecated

\tikzset{D/.style={
    preaction={draw=blue,line width=1pt},
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5, transparency group]
            \path[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
            \mySecondList \myList 
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}



\tikzset{EDR/.style={
   % preaction={draw=red,line width=1pt},    %<- remove this line
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
  next state=draw,
  width=0pt,
  persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{}\xdef\mySecondList{}}
    \pgfextra{\setcounter{tmp}{0}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
      -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
    -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
    {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \stepcounter{tmp}
    \pgfcoordinate{muemmel\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
    {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    \pgfcoordinate{feep\thetmp}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}      
    \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList (muemmel\thetmp) -- }%
    \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList (feep\thetmp) -- }}
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
      \pgfextra{\xdef\myList{\myList cycle}% 
      \xdef\mySecondList{\mySecondList cycle}}
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{\pgfextra{%\typeout{\myList,\mySecondList}
  }}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
decorate}}
% END from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419558/11820

\tikzset{EDO/.style={
  %  preaction={draw=orange,line width=1pt},    %<- remove this line
    preaction={decoration={contour lineto closed, contour distance=6pt},
      decorate,
    },
    postaction={
      insert path={%
        \pgfextra{%
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \path[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=orange,even odd rule] 
          \mySecondList \myList 
          ;
        \endpgfinterruptpath}
    }},
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node at (-.5,0) {a)};
  \path [EDO] (2.875,0) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75) -- cycle;
  \path [EDR] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0) -- cycle ;
  \fill [white] (.21,.3) rectangle (2.655,-.3);
  \path [draw, orange, line width=1pt] (2.875,0) -- ++(0,.75) -- ++(-2.875,0) -- ++(0,-.75);
  \path [draw, red, line width=1pt] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(6,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-3.125,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I note that the above code is necessarily long and compliated, so I use plain TikZ. Meaning of parameters is clear and you can change color as you like.

The filling option `even odd rule` for the `north west lines` pattern does the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,declare function={a=3;b=1.2;c=3.5;d=1;m=.2;}]
\path 
(0,0)   coordinate (A) +(m,m)   coordinate (At)
(a,b+d) coordinate (B) +(-m,-m) coordinate (Bt)
(a+c,b) coordinate (C) +(-m,-m) coordinate (Ct)
;
\draw[blue,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=red!50,even odd rule] 
(A)|-(B)|-(C)|-cycle (At)|-(Bt)|-(Ct)|-cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just improved the code.